# What electronic component is this

Tags: circuit-design, identification

This is from the circuit board in my rechargeable(via usb) LED Torchlight. What is it? What does it do?
In case it's not clear, this is what's written on it: 4054C j136 (I think it could also be jl36; not very clear). Also it's the black component in the bottom-right corner[image: A cropped out snapshot of the circuit board in question(it's cropped out because of file size)]

Comment: Have you drawn up a schematic?  Any clues as to its function or what part of the circuit it’s in?

Comment: See the answer I just posted. It is a Standalone Linear Li-Ion Battery Charger with
Thermal Regulation in ThinSOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked it up with google using "4054C IC datasheet" and found this, my first hit! The LTC®4054 is a complete constant-current/constantvoltage linear charger for single cell lithium-ion batteries. Its ThinSOT package and low external component count make the LTC4054 ideally suited for portable applications.
Furthermore, the LTC4054 is specifically designed to work within USB power specifications.
No external sense resistor is needed, and no blocking diode is required due to the internal MOSFET architecture. Thermal feedback regulates the charge current to limit the die temperature during high power operation or high ambient temperature. The charge voltage is fixed at 4.2V,and the charge current can be programmed externally with a single resistor. The LTC4054 automatically terminates the charge cycle when the charge current drops to 1/10th the programmed value after the final float voltage is reached.
When the input supply (wall adapter or USB supply) is removed, the LTC4054 automatically enters a low current state, dropping the battery drain current to less than 2mA. The LTC4054 can be put into shutdown mode, reducing the supply current to 25mA. Feel free to look up the rest of the information if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a 4054C battery managaement chip.